# Sniffer attack on mobile

Tags: mobile, sniffer

I have Nokia lumia 625. And a guy hacked it using sniffer. That's how much I know about it. He has access to all my online texts(eg. Whatsapp, messenger etc) . and also to offline carrier text messages. What do I do to resolve this problem? I have tried factory resetting but it does not work. What is a sniffer and how do I handle it?

Comment: 1. Have you been on the same wifi network?  If you did look at the link about packet analyzer. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer )  He's basically intercepting your traffic. If you backup your text messages somewhere that's how he gets access to them. Also you can wipe your phone a milion + 1 times. If you go back on that network he'll analyze your traffic data again.

Comment: I have my own wifi network. The guy was a friend and visited me once and worked on my wifi for a couple of hours. Since then he could know all my messages, wherever he might be. And yes i read about packet analyzers. I found that encryption helps. But whatsapp has a default encryption,right? I also downloaded (a self proclaimed secure messaging app). still no help. also, the online bank payment gateways would detect something and warn me that my device is not safe to proceed and would not proceed with transactions. but all my other devices on the same wifi ran smooth.

Comment: So my understanding is this: You did a factory reset. He is still able to read your messages even if he's not on the same network with you right? If so, my guess is that he probably messed with your router config to forward the traffic through a proxy to which he has access.  check the router config and see if there's anything about forwarding in there.

Comment: @FlorinCoada WhatsApp uses End2End encryption, so MITMing the traffic should not expose the data to the attacker surely? IMO this is more likely to be a keylogger?

Comment: he never had access to my phone directly. is it possible to install one remotely? And also how do we explain that on online payment gateways all my devices worked well on the very same wifi, but in my phone that warning popped up and it aborted?

Comment: @darkf Very good point! What I have in mind is this: On android you can install apps for your phone from the web if you have the account that it's registered against the device. If the same applies to microsoft, maybe he got your account details when he was on your network, and now he keeps reinstalling a keylogger on your phone.....

Comment: @FlorinCoada so the suggestion is to change ALL your account passwords?

Comment: @PrabhatChoudhary Do you use Chrome on the "other devices"? Chrome tends to be more cautious than other browsers with certificate issues. If you do use Chrome on others as well as the Phone, it's possible you have a bogus certificate on your phone. Though wiping it should have gotten rid of that!

Comment: @MikeOunsworth Well if you think about it, his friend is capturing stuff from his phone after he did a factory reset. If he introduced his passwords into various apps after his friend redeployed the keylogger, it's a chance that he knows those passwords too.  But for now, I'd check all the apps on the phone to see if there's anything strange around there.

Comment: @darkf Yes, that service is provided by microsoft.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth though i m sure that i didnt notice any malicious behaviour with any of the apps. Nothing unusual. Just a passive attack, logging all my messages, be it onine or the offline carrier texts.

Comment: @PrabhatChoudhary you would see anything malicious. If he did install an app to perform keylogging it will be probably disguised as something else entirely... Change your Windows Phone user password and do another factory reset. See if he can still steal stuff.

Comment: @FlorinCoada I did a hard reset. (guided by Microsoft Forums). The payment gateway problem is resolved. Not really sure if the he has acces to mesaages.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities how he did it:

- You and him were connected to the same WiFi network and he used a software like Dsploit that allows him to intercept the traffic and performing man in the middle attack - solution to that is use VPN software that will encrypt the connection.
- More advanced attack. He forced your mobile device by using Karma and WiFi Pinneaple to connect to his rouge access point - The best way to protect yourself from this kind of attack is to 'forget' networks as soon as you have finished using them, just remove them from the list.
- He had access to your mobile device and he installed a keylogger - solution is to reinstall to whole system in your device.

Comment: He already went through a factory reset so I assume point 3 might not apply.

Answer (score 0):

It looks likely that they have used the fact your're on a local wifi network to intercept your session traffic and capture the content.  There are a number of simple to use tools that can enable this type of attack in gaining your sessions.  Another vector is if they have created a MITM WIFI access point masquerading as a legitimate access point to capture the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I think a clean install should do the trick, except if he's in the police force, they have access to your carrier/any carrier.